# Is the customer.subscription.updated event raised when a subscription is renewed?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm confused about why Stripe's documentation suggests the `customer.subscription.updated` event is not fired when I believe it should:

- A Stripe `subscription` object has the properties `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` which would be updated whenever the customer successfully pays a subscription's invoices ( https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscriptions )
- The documentation for the `customer.subscription.updated` event states that it...

  > Occurs whenever a subscription changes. Examples would include switching from one plan to another, or switching status from trial to active.

  ...which would imply that the event would be raised if the `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` values change, but it doesn't affirm if it does or it does not in this case.

  However this third-party webpage states that it is not raised when a successful renewal is performed ( https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/stripe-webhook-event-cheatsheet#8 ).
- But raising the event just makes sense...
- And certainly if applications *only* needed to monitor a single event type (i.e. `customer.subscription.updated`) then it would greatly simplify program code without needing to also monitor `invoice.payment_succeeded`, `invoice.created` and `charge.succeeded`.
- However the documentation for the Subscription Lifecycle ( https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle ) makes absolutely no mention of the `customer.subscription.updated` event at all.

It just seems odd that such an appropriate event is not raised when it should be. The documentation also really doesn't say when the `current_period_end` and `current_period_start` values are updated either, which limits their utility.

So in my application, after receiving an `invoice.payment_succeeded` event, how can my program code determine when the customer's subscription period will end next?

Answer (score 40):

I've verified that `customer.subscription.updated` **is called when the billing period ends**.

To do this I intercepted all webhooks that occur at the end of the period (FYI: I used an AWS Lambda function that receives the events from an AWS API Gateway, then puts the events on an SQS queue :))

I agree that [the Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types) for the `customer.subscription.updated` event could be clearer and could cover this use case by saying....

> Occurs whenever a subscription changes. Examples would include
>   when the billing period ends and a new billing period begins, when
>   switching from one plan to another, or switching status from trial to
>   active.

(FYI: I would ignore the cheatsheet website altogether. They make only fleeting reference to `customer.subscription.updated` - In step 8 they are describing (poorly) the use case of "Create a customer with a plan without a trial" which wouldn't create a `customer.subscription.updated` event because this event only occurs when the subscription is updated, not when it is created. Where they do reference `customer.subscription.updated` is in context of Step 12 "Invoice charge attempt fails")

In defense of Stripes documentation regarding the lifecycle of a subscription, it does say "the following image shows the lifecycle of the **most important events** that occur" and I'd say `customer.subscription.updated` is not an *important* event in context of creating invoices and making payments.

Some details about how Stripe handles the end of a period:

- In my test, Stripe raised the `customer.subscription.updated` event approximately 2 minutes after the timestamp in the current_period_end property on the subscription. The event has two data objects associated with it. The first is the subscription with the new values on it. The second is a `previousAttributes` object with the two previous `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` values.
- Two events were generated simultaneously: `customer.subscription.updated` and `invoice.created` (this was the invoice for the period that had just elapsed).
- Around an hour after the invoice was created, three events were generated simultaneously: `invoice.payment_succeeded`, `charge.succeeded` and `invoice.updated`.

How you treat the rollover of a billing period vs. the payment status of an invoice is really up to you, and very much depends on your application type. That's the beauty of the Stripe API (and it is a thing of beauty).

In my case, I treat the rollover of a billing period separately to the payment status of an invoice. My application cares about when the billing period rolls over and makes updates to usage based on this, but any payment failures generate alerts & are handled offline.

In summary, you **can** use `customer.subscription.updated` to know when the billing period has changed.

Answer (score 4):

`customer.subscription.updated` is triggered when `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` change. These represent the **billing period**.

When `invoice.payment_succeeded` happens, it's there that you must update the information on your side (e.g.: *subscription period*):
https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#step-3-sync-with-your-site

Also more info here: https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-events-can-i-see-when-a-subscription-is-renewed

Comment: I would respectfully challenge the statement "When invoice.payment_succeeded happens, it's there that you must update the information on your side (e.g.: subscription period)" - IMHO deciding how to handle these events very much depends on the application behaviour you're trying to achieve. My preference would be to update the subscription on my side when Stripe tells me the subscription has been updated (the customer.subscription.updated event contains the subscription object). The invoice.payment_succeeded event contains the invoice object.

Comment: Agree with @SimonCurd. This had me confused to begin with as well. I've decided to only modify the subscription when customer.subscription.updated is fired - nowhere else.