# Is customer.subscription.updated a good way to handle the status of a subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972986/is-the-customer-subscription-updated-event-raised-when-a-subscription-is-renewed) question, but am still not 100% sure about how to handle recurring subscriptions. I have the following question:

- If I have a webhook for the `customer.subscription.updated`, is that
  enough to keep track of a recurring subscription? For example, according to
  the question above, when the subscription billing period changes,
  `customer.subscription.updated` is called. Will it also be called if, for example,
  a payment fails, and the status changes to past due?

Is it alright to use just the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook, or is it necessary to use the webhooks such as `invoice.payment_succeeded` for keeping track of the subscription? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to also keep track of `invoice.payment_failed` - and possibly `invoice.payment_action_required` - so you know when those happen; otherwise you should be good, ya.  You can read more about it here:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks